# Retrieve specific value in where clause in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get cmdd(@PermissionAccessoageID)value in the code and how can achieve that.

I get this error

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand to a known managed provider native type.

My code:

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[1] { new DataColumn("Pages") });

    foreach (GridViewRow row in addGridView.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("chkboxaddView") as CheckBox);
            CheckBox chkRow1 = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("chkboxaddEdit") as CheckBox);
            string aaa = row.Cells[0].Text;

            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {
                con.Open();
                var vaala = chkRow.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                var vaalaa = chkRow1.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                var val = chkaddisactive.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                var vall = chkboxisactive.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                string sqlcmd = "select AccesspageID From AccessPages where pages='" + row.Cells[0].Text + "'";

                SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, con);
                cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmdd.ExecuteScalar();

                string query = "add3tables";         //Stored procedure name 
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);  //creating  SqlCommand  object
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  //here we declaring command type as stored procedure

                // adding parameters to SqlCommand below 
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtaddrolename.Text.ToString());
                string unique_string = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleID ", unique_string);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive ", val);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermissionRoleID ", unique_string);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@View ", vaala);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edit ", vaalaa);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermissionAccessoageID ", cmdd);

                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

            if (chkRow1.Checked == false)
            {
                var vaala = chkRow.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                var vaalaa = chkRow1.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                var val = chkaddisactive.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                var vall = chkboxisactive.Checked ? 1 : 0;

                SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select AccesspageID From AccessPages where pages='" + aaa + "'", con);
                con.Open();

                cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                string query = "add3tables";         //Stored procedure name 
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);  //creating  SqlCommand  object
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  //here we declaring command type as stored procedure

                // adding parameters to SqlCommand below 
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtaddrolename.Text.ToString());
                string unique_string = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleID ", unique_string);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive ", val);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermissionRoleID ", unique_string);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@View ", vaala);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edit ", vaalaa);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermissionAccessoageID ", cmdd);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why do you want to get the value of cmdd(@PermissionAccessoageID)? Is it the last inserted row or something else?

Comment: Cmdd is already inserted row in the database. i want to retrieve the AccesspageID

Comment: Your first select statement seems to be useless. You never use the result  anywhere in your code. in your second if statement, you don't even execute it.

Comment: @Vinoth What is `add3tables` ? What are you're trying to do here ? You're using the `SqlCommand` API is a completely wrong way ! The parameters needs to appear in the query you're executing. This is not your case.

Comment: Side Note: Accessing the database inside a for loop is a red light for efficiency. If you have another option, it would be better.

Comment: @ user3185569 add3tables is a storedprocedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to use your result of the select statement and need to assign it to a variable.

In your first if block you actually execute it, but don't use the result. In your second if block you forgot the `.ExecuteScalar()` call.

```
object oAccesspageID = cmdd.ExecuteScalar();
int? AccesspageID = (int?)(!Convert.IsDBNull(oAccesspageID) ? oAccesspageID : null);
/* ... code ommitted*/

//assuming @PermissionAccessoageID is int
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermissionAccessoageID ", AccesspageID.Value);
```

Since ExecuteScalar can return null, if no results have been found, you need to account for that in some way. You may want to add another `if(AccesspageID.HasValue) { }` call before invoking your SProc, to make sure it doesn't try to run with invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the issue:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermissionAccessoageID ", cmdd);
```

`cmdd` is of type `SqlCommand`, you can't have a parameter with that type.